# The load in some Google App Engine instances and very small in others. Why?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, load-balancing

As you can see in the following snapshot the load in some of the dynamic instances is huge (more than 20k requests) while in other are very small.

[image]

Why is this happening? Shouldn't GAE distribute uniformly the load??

Comment: We see the same thing and I always suspected it has something to do with Java's high loading latency, but I'd like to know - particularly in the context of instance billing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I got from a Google App Engine expert:

> App Engine request scheduling uses several heuristics for routing requests to application instances. At low QPS it stays in affinity scheduling mode and routes majority of requests to instances that have most recently responded to the health check and handled requests successfully. That would explain why you see this variation in number of requests for each instance. As you ramp up the application traffic, load should even out across all instances.

I also asked what was the policy GAE follow to shut down the instances. I see that many of them are up even if they are not receiving any request

> Dynamic instances that are not serving requests get garbage collected eventually. However, you only get billed for 15 additional minutes after they serve the last request. Please refer to this doc for additional information on instance billing.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/billing#different_on_demand_instance_resident

Answer (score 2):

If the load would be balanced across the active dynamic instances then they'd rarely become idle (only when the **entire** app's traffic would drop to almost nothing) thus it'd be difficult to dynamically shut them down.

More info here:

- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/scaling#scaling_dynamic_instances
- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managing-resources#instances

Comment: I do agree that the info in the snapshot looks a bit suspect - I'd imagine several of those low-active dynamic instances should have been shutdown automatically? (but I'm not too sure - I didn't use any scaling customisations yet).